# I want to view many fields from 3 table to show them in same page and same query

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hi 
I have this three table . and i have form to put the id_student then the view must be :
the name + surname +father then 
the subjects and the mark of each subjects 
how i can do that ?

i try this :

```
select students.name, grade.marks 
from students 
INNER JOIN grade ON students.id_students = grade.id_students
```

Comment: select
                    students.name,
                    grade.marks
                    from  
                    students
                    INNER JOIN grade
                    ON students.id_students = grade.id_students

Comment: Add it to your question ans specify the problem with the query

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what else you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you need to join with the third table as well. Considering you want all the column from 3 table do something like

```
select students.*, 
grade.*,
Courses.*
from grade 
INNER JOIN courses on grade.id_subject = courses.id_subject
INNER JOIN students ON students.id_students = grade.id_students
WHERE students.id_students=690
```

Comment: doesn't work . i put this on the browser :index.php?id_students=690. and show all data in all this table

Comment: Add that as a condition to the query to get that particular row. That's why you should clearly mention this in your posts.